# Allow dots in URL using regex

Tags: regex, url, url-routing

How can I allow a dot in an URL using Regex? Any advice?

thanks

Comment: While I'm not sure what this has to do with regex, dots are allowed in the url, just not at the end.

Comment: i have a url with parameter like http://foo.bar/value1/value2. the two values and include dots, e.g. http://foo.bar/14.23/12.64. Therefore I need regex to allow these kind of dotted-values (so my framework doesn't recognize it as "file).

Comment: What framework are you talking about?

Comment: express.js a web-framework for node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` in a regex allows any character (except newlines, depending on the engine and its options), so you have to escape it as `\.`

Answer (score 6):

`\.` will allow you to match a dot. How you insert that into your regex depends on how you've created your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're being vague, so will I:

```
\.
```

There's the regex to allow a dot.

Answer (score 0):

use the \ to escape native match chrs